# replace double quotes with single quotes in a string

Tags: php

I know this sounds simple, and probably is, but I can't seem ot get this working. Just want to replace all occurences of a double quote with a single quote...tired this but it doesn't work:

```
$con = str_replace("\"", "'", $content);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn'#t work"?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? That's the very definition of what you want to do...  Can you provide examples of what you are providing, what it's giving, and what you're expecting?

Comment: Well If i echo the string the double quotes are still there...

a string with "double quotes"

then after my code it's still 

a string with "double quotes"

I want a string with 'double quotes'

Comment: What string do you echo? Note that you’re using two different variables: `$content` and `$con`.

Comment: after your replace, are you still echoing $content or $con? You should be echoing $con

Comment: Then the "double quotes" aren't probably double quotes. Maybe there are htmlentities &quot;?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or:

`$con = str_replace(chr(34), chr(39), $content);`

Answer (score 1):

What you do is correct and should work. If it doesn't, then you may only SEE double quotes, but in reality these are other characters. Possible is html `&quot;` character rendered as ". There are also several chars very similar to double quotes. hey 'happen' especially when pasting text from word or openoffice. You'll include all possibilities in str_replace (it can take arrays of strings as parameters).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with input from a form.

I used `&ampquot;` for my search string and it worked great.

```
$con = str_replace("&ampquot;", "'", $content);
```